# Change or remove RatingBar focus color

Tags: android, focus, ratingbar

I have RatingBar and style. I want to remove focusing color at the RatingBar.

My empty RatingBar's colors:
[image]
My RatingBar's focusing color:
[image]
I want to remove focusing color:
[image]

theme:

```
 <style name="CustomRatingBar" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/lightTransparentBlack</item>
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/yellow</item>
</style>
```

layout:

```
<RatingBar
  android:id="@+id/ratingBar"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_gravity="center"
  android:theme="@style/CustomRatingBar"
  android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
  android:numStars="5"
  android:stepSize="1" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On API 21 and higher, you can change the color of the filled stars with

```
 android:progressTint="@color/color"
```

and the color of the stroke with

```
 android:progressBackgroundTint="@color/color"
```

Comment: Thank you. Has any solution for < API 21